# Use Cauchy formula to solve $\int _0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{a\cos t+ b\sin t +c} $ given $\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}=1<c$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Use Cauchy formula to solve $$\int _0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{a \cos t+ b \sin t +c} $$ Given $\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}=1<c$.
I tried a variable substitution, but nothing elegant. Can anyone solve it using Cauchy formula?

Edit: there are simpler solutions, but the challenge is to solve it with complex analysis.

Comment: @SameerBaheti yes

Comment: Well, Cauchy's Integral formula is not at my level, however, you can start with $$\sin x=\frac{2\tan x/2}{1+\tan^2x/2}\;,\cos x=\frac{1-\tan^2x/2}{1+\tan^2x/2}$$ and let $\displaystyle\tan x/2=u$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

With $z=e^{it}$,
$$\int\frac{dt}{a\cos t+b\sin t+c}=\oint\frac{2\,dz}{iz(a(z+z^{-1})-ib(z-z^{-1})+2c)}$$ and you have two nice poles.

Comment: please it seems that you have the right direction!

Comment: (+1) for the only post that read Tags:  "Complex-Analysis, Cauchy-Integral-Formula."  Title: "Use Cauchy formula to solve ..." Main Body Intro:  "Use Cauchy formula to solve ... ".   And I hope that you're staying safe and healthy my friend.

Comment: @MarkViola: thanks for the care, same to you.

Comment: can you show a full solution? I am not sure what can I do with 2 poles, as Cauchy formula shouldn't work with this kind of poles? or should  I take the inverse?

Comment: @MrP: can you find them ? In general they are simple.

Comment: yeah that is easy, but I get 4 poles. not just two. and I can't understand how can I use Cauchy formula

Comment: @MrP: you can't have four poles with a quadratic denominator ! (By the way, I said *simple*, not easy.)

Comment: but the relation between a and b is also quadratic.

Comment: @MrP: what ? Aren't $a$ and $b$ known parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

*This can be done without taking the help of integration limits too.*

> Evaluate $$\int \frac{dt}{a \cos t+ b \sin t +c} $$
> ,where $\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}=1<c$.

I don't know what Cauchy's formula you are talking about. But here is a nice way to do it.

Since $\sin t=\frac{2\tan(\frac x2)}{1+\tan^2(\frac x2)},\cos t=\frac{1-\tan^2(\frac x2)}{1+\tan^2(\frac x2)}$, we can write it as(You may stop and try it yourself at this point)
\begin{align*}
&\Rightarrow\int \frac{\sec^2(\frac x2)dt}{a(1-\tan^2(\frac x2))+2b\tan(\frac x2)+c(1+\tan^2(\frac x2))}\\
&=\int\frac{2du}{a(1-u^2)+2bu+c(1+u^2)}\\
&=\frac2{c-a}\int\frac{du}{\left(u+\frac{b}{c-a}\right)^2+\frac{c+a}{c-a}-\frac{b^2}{(c-a)^2}}\\
&=\frac2{c-a}\int\frac{du}{\left(u+\frac{b}{c-a}\right)^2+\frac{c^2-(a^2+b^2)}{(c-a)^2}}\\
&=\frac2{c-a}\int\frac{du}{\left(u+\frac{b}{c-a}\right)^2+K^2}\\
&=\frac2{(c-a)K^2}\int\frac{du}{\left(\frac{u+\frac{b}{c-a}}{K}\right)^2+1}\\
\end{align*}
Can you make the substitution and finish it?

Comment: Tags:  "Complex-Analysis, Cauchy-Integral-Formula."  Title: "Use Cauchy formula to solve ..." Main Body Intro:  "Use Cauchy formula to solve ... ".  So, what did you not understand??

Comment: @MarkViola Ah! I don't read tags usually. I guess because I never needed to. Also, the OP claimed to have tried variable substitution yet to fail and I thought that such a solution could work too. Or the OP might have tried a substitution for Cauchy's formula and not needed this, I don't know. But I don't think I should delete it for it might be helpful to others.

Comment: That's fine.  But it was more than clear that the OP was seeking a solution using contour integration in the complex plane.

Comment: FYI ... I was not the down voter.

Answer (score 0):

It may still be desirable to integrate as follows,

\begin{align}
& \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{a\cos t+ b\sin t +c}\\
=& \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos (t-\theta) +c}
= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{2dt}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos t +c}\\
= & \int_0^{\pi} \frac{2dt}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos^2\frac t2+c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\
 = & \int_0^{\pi} \frac{2\sec^2\frac t2 dt}{(c+ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} )+( c- \sqrt{a^2+b^2} )\tan^2\frac t2}\\
=& \frac{4}{\sqrt{c^2-a^2-
b^2} }\tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{c+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}  }\tan\frac t2 \right)_0^{\pi}\\
=& \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{c^2-a^2-b^2} }
\end{align}

Comment: The shift of $\frac\pi4$ is not correct.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - realized; thx for the note

Comment: Tags:  "Complex-Analysis, Cauchy-Integral-Formula."  Title: "Use Cauchy formula to solve ..." Main Body Intro:  "Use Cauchy formula to solve ... ".  So, what did you not understand??

Comment: FYI ... I was not the down voter